# How can I use codebird.js twitter library?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I want to use codebird.js twitter library to get latest tweet for specific author via new Twitter API1.1

https://github.com/mynetx/codebird-js

I didn't find any tutorial or getting started guide for using it ..

regards

Comment: Looking at the source code, it is very well commented and is fairly easy to follow if you wish to take the time.  However, it is just a wrapper for the http requests, and really just presents another set of strings you'll have to memorize for commands.  I had much more success in the past learning the proper Twitter API from the following page: https://dev.twitter.com/console.  If you want a non-codebird solution, I'd be more than happy to provide one as an answer below if you request it.  Good luck!

Comment: I'll request it. I'm just looking for a simple way to send quotes from an article to twitter. Pretty simple stuff, really.

Answer (score 1):

You have enough documentation here:

https://code.google.com/p/codebird/wiki/GettingStarted

Commented by @Jublo

The project has since moved to GitHub and is documented here: github.com/jublonet/codebird-js.

Comment: The link's not working

Comment: The project has since moved to GitHub and is documented here: https://github.com/jublonet/codebird-js.